# Understand file owner

Tags: php, filesystems

I want understood who is file owner.

If I write this

```
echo fileowner("index.php");`
```

I obtain id, but when I write this

```
var_dump( posix_getpwuid(fileowner("index.php"))  );
```

result is `bool(false)`

why `posix_getpwuid` not returns info? php version is 5.2.42

Comment: are you running linux? maybe with SELinux enabled??

Comment: Does the user for the returned ID exist?

Comment: -jere Yes, linux. about SELinux enabled I dont know, how this can I understand?

-Darius I am dont understood what you mean?

Comment: what distro? run `sestatus` or `cat /etc/sysconfig/selinux` and post its output

Comment: Afaik, `posix_` functions are only available on CLI.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely SELinux prevents `posix_getpwuid()` to resolve UID.